# Find Xpath for price for Content Egg Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, xpath, woocommerce, google-chrome-extension, plugins

I use Content Egg and i have problem to find Xpath for price in this page https://www.mobiglia.rankingweb.it/motosega-husqvarna-120-mark-ii/

I use ChroPath for Chrome but i think take the correct xpath.

Tnks

Comment: What XPath did you try?

Comment: I don't know Xpath at all. So with the Chrome extension I recovered this 
//body[1]/div[2]/div[2]/main[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]/ins[1]/span[1]/bdi[1]

Comment: I use this but dont work //div[@class='fusion-column-wrapper']//span[@class='woocommerce-Price-amount']